# Matrix Congruence and Quadratic Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, matrix-congruences

Let A $\in$ K$^n$$^,$$^n$ be a symmetric matrix over a field K. Define f(A) = { t$^2$ det(A) : t $\in$ K } and g(A) = {$x^T$A$x$ : $x \in $ K$^n$ } .

WTS if A,B are **congruent** f(A) = f(B) and g(A) = g(B)

Does the Sylvester's Law of inertia apply in this question and how does it?

I have so far: A, B are congruent if there exists an invertible matrix P such that B = P$^T$AP. Hence f(B) = f(P$^T$AP) = { t$^2$ det(P$^T$AP) : t$\in$ K } ...

For g, a similar approach doesn't seem to work and I think I need to use that congruent matrices have the same inertia but I can't get my head around it

Comment: This is because $x \mapsto Px$ is an isomorphism in $K^n$.

Comment: I don't understand: you have asked exactly the same question 4 hours ago (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1999425), without answers, then deleted it half an hour ago... ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Well, perhaps it is just logical: he asked, nobody answered within 4 hours and experience shows it most likely won't be answered then, so in order not to repeat delete first question and then re-post.

Comment: @K. Am I right deducing $\;f(A):=\left\{\,t^2\cdot\det A\;/\;t\in K\,\right\}\;$ is a set in $\;K\;$ , whereas $\;g(A)\;$ is a set in $\;K^n\;$ ? And what does WTS stand for?

Comment: That is right Sir. And WTS is 'want to show'. Thank you for you help. Much appreciated

Comment: @JeanMarie What are you talking about?

Comment: I have said what I thought. Nothing more. I will not polemicate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was a similar question created 4 hours ago and deleted half an hour ago, hence not found in the duplicate records. He wants only his homework done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$A\cong B\iff \exists\,\;\text{invertible}\;P\;\;s.t.\;\;A=P^tBP\implies$$

$$\det A=(\det P)^2\det B\;,\;\;\text{ and then}$$

$$t^2\det A\in f(A)\implies t^2\det A=t^2((\det P)^2\det B)=(t\det P)^2\det B\in f(B)\implies$$

$$f(A)\subset f(B)$$

Try to complete this part now...

As for the other one:

$$x^tAx=x^t(P^tBP)x=(Px)^t B(Px)\implies g(A)\subset g(B)$$

and now try to complete also this part.